# Hide columns that are constant across a small number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns a small number of rows (usually 2-5) but a huge number of columns (several hundred).  The rows are mostly identical, save for a few places.  I would like to quickly identify them by hiding columns which are constant (e.g., I have 5 products, all of which cost $3, so the cost column should be suppressed). Is there an elegant way to do this using MySQL?  If it helps, most of the columns are numerical.

Here's a tiny example: Suppose my initial query returns

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
 1  | x  | a  | 3.14
 1  | x  | b  | 3.14
```

Columns 1, 2 and 4 are "constant", while column 3 is not. Therefore I would like a secondary query to return only column 3:

```
|col3|
| a  |
| b  |
```

The problem is that manually finding a small number of non-constant columns is quite difficult with a large number of constant columns.

Comment: Brent, you might want to [merge your two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit your own content without requiring moderation.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Consider doing it in your app.  SQL is not brilliant at formatting tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Columns are not dynamic. They can't be suppressed on the result because at that point it's too late. You have two options

1. Unpivot

   ```
   id|ident|x|y
   1 | foo |1|2
   ```

   Becomes

   ```
   id|ident|key|val
   1 | foo | x |2
   1 | foo | y |2
   ```

   The schema is fixed from that point and you can return just what you need.
2. Use dynamic SQL. The server returns sql that you issue against the server.

You could also fix the schema, if most of those columns are redundant modify the schema.

## Update

> I think perhaps you misunderstood my goal. I'm working with a query that returns something like: [...] I want to turn hide/supress the columns which are "constant," as in they don't change from row to row. That would turn the above table into...

I'm very sure I don't misunderstand your goal. We have *at least* one question a week that is along the same lines we have to turn around for the very same reason. [In fact, a year ago yesterday I asked a similar question out of desperation thinking there may be a better way, and was turned around for the same reason.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159280/2639). I can still quote Erwin's relevant parts here,

> Column names and types cannot be dynamic. SQL demands to know number, names and types of resulting columns at call time. Either by explicit declaration or from information in the system catalogs (That's what happens with `SELECT * FROM tbl`: Postgres looks up the registered table definition.) ... **You want Postgres to derive resulting columns from data in a user table. Not going to happen.** [...] One way or the other, you need two round trips to the server. Either you create a cursor and then walk through it. Or you create a temp table and then select from it. Or you register a type and use it in the call.

Your use case here is slightly different, but you should still read the above bolded parts at least 15 times, because it has to sink through.

Then you've got to either,

1. Change the format you're will to accept from the server.
2. Process the result set on the server that generates the right query, and then issue that query back to the server.

For your example

```
CREATE TABLE tinyexample(id,ident,key,val)
AS VALUES
  ( 1, 'foo', 'x', 2),
  ( 1, 'foo', 'y', 2);
```

What you want is something like this. Note this is *not* the best way to do this, you could save a round trip by running this in a function.

```
SELECT FORMAT (
  $$
    SELECT FORMAT(
      'SELECT %%s FROM %%I.%%I.%%I;',
      array_to_string(array_remove(ARRAY[%s]::text[],null), ', '),
      %s,
      %s,
      %s
    ) AS inner
    FROM %I.%I.%I;
  $$,
  colexpr,
  quote_literal(table_catalog),
  quote_literal(table_schema),
  quote_literal(table_name),
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name
) AS outer
FROM (
  SELECT
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    string_agg(  format($$CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT %I) > 1 THEN %s END$$, column_name, quote_literal(column_name)), ', '  ) AS colexpr
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_catalog = 'test'
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name = 'tinyexample'
  GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
) AS t;
```

This seems like a mess, most of that's not me though. We have

1. Issue our first query to the information_schema to get the column listing. Without this you'd have to statically type the columns. That's no fun. This returns query "outer".
2. Issue our second query ("outer") to find out which columns are *not* distinct based on their values. This returns query "inner".
3. Issue our third query ("inner") which returns the resultset we want.

Answer (score 0):

As Evan noted in his answer, you could use dynamic SQL to determine the answer.

As a first stab, I'd try to create a stored procedure that works like this:

1. Generate the full result set, and put in in a temporary table.
2. Create a variable `colList`, initially as an empty string
3. For each column:

   - Count the number of distinct values
   - If the count is greater than 1, add the column name (preceded by a comma) to `colList`
4. Build your SQL statement in another variable:

   ```
   SET stmt = CONCAT( "SELECT id, otherUniqueColumn"
                     ,colList
                     ,",trailing_unique_column FROM tmpTable;")
   ```
5. Then, execute your statement.

As noted, you could accomplish the same thing by unpivoting your data, then re-pivoting it.

When you unpivot your data, for each row in your result set, you'd get *n* rows (where *n* is the number of columns that are candidates to be eliminated). those rows should consist of any columns that uniquely identify a row (as we need to reassemble the rows when we're done), and two new columns: `column_name` (the actual name of an eliminatable column), and `value` (the value from the eliminatable column). Again, these would presumably be stored in a temporary table (let's call it `myUnpivotedResults`).

*NOTE*: you have to be able to cast all values from the eliminatable columsn to a common type, while retaining the information you want in your final results; if you can't do this, this method won't work.

In similar fashion to the other way detailed above, we now eliminate all columns that have only one value. First, let's put the `column_name`s we want to hide in a second temp table:

```
INSERT INTO myColumnsToHide (column_name, myCount)
SELECT column_name, COUNT(DISTINCT value)
  FROM myUnpivotedResults
 GROUP BY column_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) > 1
;
```

Next, remove those columns from our unpivoted data:

```
DELETE t1
  FROM myUnpivotedResults t1
         INNER JOIN myColumnsToHide t2 ON (t1.column_name = t2.column_name)
;
```

Then, re-pivot the data - only the columns with more than one distinct value will be left.

For information on pivoting, unpivoting, stored procedures or other concepts mentioned here, search existing questions on the site; you should find plenty of existing questions and answers.