# Fast long-to-wide reshaping in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, amazon-rds

I am trying to change a *really* long table (1955451890 rows -- 278 Gb on the DB) to a wide format using `crosstab` from the `tablefunc` extension. Following several examples from SO (i.e. [Crosstab with unknown format](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159280/how-do-i-generate-a-pivoted-cross-join-where-the-resulting-table-definition-is-u) and the [PostgreSQL official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tablefunc.html)) I have come with a working code, but it's taking ages to run in fairly big AWS RDS instance.

The data looks like this:

```
| id_source | date       | t | geo_id | var_1 | var_2 |
|-----------|------------|---|--------|-------|-------|
| 3         | 2002-01-01 | 1 | 6086   | 3.4   | 4.5   |
| 3         | 2002-01-02 | 2 | 7888   | 6.7   | 2.9   |
| 3         | 2002-01-03 | 3 | 6732   | 5.8   | 6     |
| 4         | 2002-01-01 | 1 | 7888   | 5.8   | 3.4   |
| 4         | 2002-01-02 | 2 | 6015   | 6     | 10    |
| 4         | 2002-01-03 | 3 | 4332   | 8     | 12.5  |
| 7         | 2002-01-01 | 1 | 6086   | 5     | 7.9   |
| 7         | 2002-01-02 | 2 | 6732   | 5.7   | 7.9   |
| 7         | 2002-01-03 | 3 | 7888   | 2.3   | 6     |
```

And ideally, I would have something like this:

```
| geo_id | date       | t   | var_1_id_3 | var_1_id_4 | var_1_id_7 | var_2_id_3 | var_2_id_4 | var_2_id_7 |
|--------|------------|-----|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 6086   | 2002-01-01 | 1   | 3.4        |            | 5          | 4.5        |            | 5          |
| 6086   | 2002-01-02 | 2   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 6086   | 2002-01-03 | 3   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 7888   | 2002-01-01 | 1   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 7888   | 2002-01-02 | 2   | 6.7        |            |            |            | 2.9        |            |
| 7888   | 2002-01-03 | 3   |            |            | 2.3        |            |            | 6          |
| 6732   | 2002-01-01 | 1   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 6732   | 2002-01-02 | 2   |            |            | 5.7        |            |            | 7.9        |
| 6732   | 2002-01-03 | 3   | 5.8        |            |            | 6          |            |            |
| 6015   | 2002-01-01 | 1   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 6015   | 2002-01-02 | 2   |            | 6          |            |            | 10         |            |
| 6015   | 2002-01-03 | 3   |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| ...    | ...        | ... | ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        |
```

[It seems really sparse, but is just the example I used].

Following the linked documentation I tried the following query. Here I use

1. `CROSSTAB(text, text)` with the first element being the data to reshape and the second element being the categories to represent as columns.
2. Building on the SO question, I add a `pgpsql` part to dynamically set the name of the columns. I have several id_sources, and stating categories manually would be painful

```sql
SELECT $$ SELECT * FROM crosstab (
    'SELECT source_id
            zcta_id,
            date_day,
            t,
            distance_nearest
     FROM results.distances_aod_coal_plants_energy
     ORDER BY 1, 2, 3',
    'SELECT DISTINCT "distance_to_plant" || facility_id AS col
    FROM hysplit_partitions.coal_plants'
    ) AS ct (zcta_id CHARACTER VARYING,
              date_day DATE,
              t INTEGER,
              $$
            || string_agg(quote_ident(id_source::CHARACTER), ' DOUBLE PRECISION, ' order BY id_source) || ' DOUBLE PRECISION )'
            from results.distances_aod_coal_plants_energy;
```

The query runs, but after ~3 hr of computing time I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741815 bytes by 19 more bytes.
```

I know PostreSQL is not particularly friendly to this reshaping, compared to Python's `pandas` or R's `tidyr`, but loading this sort of data is not straight forward on any of these options, and I do have a strong preference to keep my data inside my DB.

There's an alternative to do this reshapinng either using chunks or table partitioning?