# Use values from one column as column names and sum data from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, pivot

I'm going to do my best to describe this. So I have 3 tables as follows:

**project**

| id | title | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Project One | 50 |
| 1002 | Project two | 50 |

**metric**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Number of exhibits |
| 102 | Number of stakeholders |

**project_metric**

| id | metric_id | project_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1001 | 10 |
| 2 | 101 | 1002 | 20 |
| 3 | 102 | 1001 | 5 |
| 4 | 102 | 1002 | 33 |

What I'm trying to do is write a query that will produce the below result.

| project_title | Number of exhibits | Number of stakeholders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project One | 10 | 5 |
| Project Two | 20 | 33 |

I'm not going to paste any of my attempts because they're pathetic.

A couple of notes:

1. PostgreSQL version is 9.5 on this db.
2. **(IMPORTANT)** This query will be implemented inside a long query that displays some 65 columns of information about a Project, but for brevity obviously I've omitted some project attributes. I'll post a partial snippet of the current query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.title AS "Project Title", d.name AS "Center/Department",

   // This is a query that currently exists in the long query I mentioned.
    (SELECT DISTINCT string_agg(DISTINCT re.name, ', ') AS "Research Exchange"
     FROM research_exchange re
         JOIN project_research_exchange pre ON pre.research_exchange_id = re.id
     WHERE pre.project_id = p.id)

FROM project p
    LEFT JOIN department d ON p.department_id = d.id
GROUP BY p.title
ORDER BY p.title
```

Comment: Postgres 9.5 is too old. Consider upgrading to a current version. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: I am thinking to do that, but it runs on an old grails and jdk8 so I'm not that confident to do that yet. I dumped a copy and testing it locally just to see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many result columns I would suggest a crosstab query. If you are unfamiliar, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

Your test case seems misleading as it would not require aggregation. Assuming multiple rows per project and metric in reality, you need to aggregate sums first.

```
SELECT p.title AS project_title, ct.*
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT project_id, metric_id, sum(value) AS sum_val
   FROM   project_metric
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2'
 , $$SELECT unnest('{101, 102}'::int[])$$    -- more ... ①, ③
   ) AS ct(project_id int
         , "Number of exhibits" bigint
         , "Number of stakeholders" bigint)  -- more ... ②
JOIN   project p ON p.id = ct.project_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=87b87fdb04b7657c5af1f6912688afad)*

Aggregate and cross-tabulate the core table *before* joining. That's substantially cheaper.

What's more, no need to join to table `metric` at all if we translate `metric_id` to `name` as output column in the `crosstab()` function call directly. Just make sure to keep the array in the second function parameter ① in sync with the column definition list ②.

If you have many result columns (*"columns of information"*), or their number is changing dynamically, consider building the statement dynamically.
See:

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159280/how-do-i-generate-a-pivoted-cross-join-where-the-resulting-table-definition-is-u/159286#159286)
- [PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087244/939860)

About dollar-quoting ③:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)

Comment: Very helpful, appreciated. I have been testing crosstab for the past two days, what I didn't think of was calling project_id and use it for the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

The display of multiple rows to columns can be accomplished but utilising a SQL Pivot. This can be accomplished using [CrossTab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html) in PostgrSQL.

Using your example tables above

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(
    ID INT,
    Title VARCHAR(20),
    Department_ID INT
 );
 
CREATE TABLE Metric
(
    ID INT,
    Name  VARCHAR(50)
 );
 
CREATE TABLE Project_Metric
(
    ID INT,
    Metric_ID INT,
    Project_ID INT,
    Value INT    

);

INSERT INTO Project(ID,Title,Department_ID) VALUES (1001,'Project One',50);
INSERT INTO Project(ID,Title,Department_ID) VALUES (1002,'Project Two',50);

INSERT INTO Metric(ID,Name) VALUES(101,'Number of Exhibits');
INSERT INTO Metric(ID,Name) VALUES(102,'Number of Stakeholders');

INSERT INTO Project_Metric(ID,Metric_ID,Project_ID,Value) VALUES(1,101,1001,10);
INSERT INTO Project_Metric(ID,Metric_ID,Project_ID,Value) VALUES(1,101,1002,20);
INSERT INTO Project_Metric(ID,Metric_ID,Project_ID,Value) VALUES(1,102,1001,5);
INSERT INTO Project_Metric(ID,Metric_ID,Project_ID,Value) VALUES(1,102,1002,33);
```

Using Crosstab

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('Select 
  PR.Title,
  ME.Name,
  PM.Value
 FROM
   Project_Metric PM
 JOIN
   Project PR 
  ON 
    PR.ID = PM.Project_ID
  JOIN
    Metric ME
  ON
   ME.ID = PM.Metric_ID') AS cr (Project_Title VARCHAR(20),NumberOfExhibits INT,NumberOfStakeHolders INT)
ORDER BY Project_Title;
```

This gives the required results as above.

You should avoid using SQL key words such as [Value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as column names.

Comment: Thanks, it did work. It's amazing how it saved me some 200 lines of repetitive subqueries.

Comment: Oops. Quick update, this actually doesn't sum up, the values rather it displays individual values. which then repeats the same project title as many times.